# On the first time or at the first time

Tags: prepositions

> I realized him on/at the first time I enter the room.

Which preposition should I use “on” or “at” in sentence above or Does both have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English :
(for) the first/second/last etc time. for example:

> Gerry had just had back surgery for the third time in two years.
>
> I realized him for the first time I enter the room.

Comment: "I realized him for the first time I enter the room." Isn't that still ungrammatical? "Realized" is awkward and it would be "entered", no?

Comment: "For the first time" is a phrase that makes sense, and "the first time I entered the room" is a phrase that makes sense, but "for the first time I entered the room" doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you're trying to say, but I'm guessing it's this:

> I realized it was him the first time I entered the room.

The phrase "I realized it was him" tells you what happened and the phrase "the first time I entered the room" tells you when it happened. No preposition should be used here.